# Where I get download link to download magento2.0.0 community edition?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

In my current project, we use magento 2.0.0 community edition. Now I see many core files are modified by previous developers. But to identify those core file **I need original magento 2.0.0 community edition package**. But, now it is not available for download from magento.com site.

If any one give me the download link from any site to download original magento 2.0.0 community edition, or if any one have this package with his/her then if you share that package with me I shall ever remain grateful to you.

Comment: I guess this is Magento 2.0. https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0 Try to take a clone from there.

Answer (score 4):

Download the package from [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.0.0)

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases/tag/2.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Link to 2.0.0 Version is here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/archive/2.0.0.zip

Easily found via: https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 2):

The most recent versions of Magento Community Edition can be found here  : https://magento.com/tech-resources/download